# what does canonical factorization means in Bayes Net?

Tags: probability

Can someone please explain what this sentence means "a Bayes net specifies a canonical factorization of a probability distribution into the product of the conditional distribution for each variable conditioned on its parents"? Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This means that $$p(x) = \prod_{v \in V} p(x_v|x_{\text{pa}(v)})$$

So you can construct the joint probability function by multiplying conditional probabilities. Consider the following: [image]

Then $$P(a,b,c, e_1,e_2, e_2) = P(a) \cdot P(b) \cdot P(c) \cdot P(e_1|a,b,c) \cdot P(e_2|a,b,c) \cdot P(e_3|e_1, e_2)$$

In other words, we factored the joint probability into a product of conditional probabilities based on the above graph.